# Drag'n'drop: Element not staying at its original position when I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, element

I am writing my own Drag'n'drop functionality for one of my projects and I am running into an issue. All my "draggable" elements are inside a container with `display:flex`. On mousedown event on one of this elements I set the `position` to `absolute` so I would be able to set the `left` and `top` properties of the element when I am dragging. Here is what I am doing:

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#big-container")
var dragging = false;
var draggedObject;
let shiftX=0;
let shiftY=0;
document.querySelectorAll(".draggable").forEach((draggable,index) => {
    draggable.style.order = index;
    draggable.draggable =false;
    draggable.ondragstart = ()=>{return false}
    draggable.addEventListener("mousedown",ev =>{
        draggedObject = draggable;
        shiftX = ev.offsetX+5;
        shiftY = ev.offsetY+5;
        draggable.style.position = "absolute";
        draggable.style.left = (ev.clientX - shiftX) + 'px';
        draggable.style.top = (ev.clientY - shiftY) + 'px';
        dragging = true;
        let placeholder = document.createElement("div");
        placeholder.id = "placeholder";
        placeholder.style.order = draggable.style.order;
        container.appendChild(placeholder);
    })

})

document.addEventListener("mousemove", ev =>{
    if(dragging){
        draggedObject.style.left = ev.clientX - shiftX + 'px';
        draggedObject.style.top = ev.clientY - shiftY + 'px';
    }
})

document.addEventListener("mouseup",ev =>{
    if(dragging){
        draggedObject.style.position = 'static'
        let placeholder = document.querySelector("#placeholder");
        container.removeChild(placeholder);
        dragging = false
    }
})
```

```css
/* the :not(:last-of-type(div)) is there so the console doesn't get affected */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
}
.draggable {
    width: 90px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}


#placeholder {
    width: 90px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: dashed grey 5px;
}
```

```html
<body draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;">
<div id = "big-container" style ="display: flex; background-color: rgb(76, 104, 95); width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(204, 125, 111);" class="draggable"></div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(170, 214, 120);" class="draggable"></div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(129, 212, 167);" class="draggable"></div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(162, 137, 196);" class="draggable"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that on mousedown the element should stay where it was and after that when I move my mouse to move the element as well.(the anchor point should be where I clicked the element)
I am doing `shiftX = ev.offsetX+5;` because I need to account for the element's margin.

The issue is when I click on a element(and don't move my mouse at all), you can see a little shift in the element's position. It is very minor(maybe 1 or 2px) and is not happening in all places(some zones in the element do not introduce this position shift)

Do you guys have any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the actual position.

```js
let container = document.querySelector("#big-container");
var dragging = false;
var draggedObject;
let shiftX = 0;
let shiftY = 0;
document.querySelectorAll(".draggable").forEach((draggable, index) => {
  draggable.style.order = index;
  draggable.draggable = false;
  draggable.ondragstart = () => {
    return false;
  };
  draggable.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev) => {
    draggedObject = draggable;
    var x = draggable.getBoundingClientRect().top - 5;
    var y = draggable.getBoundingClientRect().left - 5;
    shiftX = ev.offsetX + 5;
    shiftY = ev.offsetY + 5;
    draggable.style.position = "absolute";
    draggable.style.left = y + "px";
    draggable.style.top = x + "px";
    dragging = true;
    let placeholder = document.createElement("div");
    placeholder.id = "placeholder";
    placeholder.style.order = draggable.style.order;
    container.appendChild(placeholder);
  });
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (ev) => {
  if (dragging) {
    draggedObject.style.left = ev.clientX - shiftX + "px";
    draggedObject.style.top = ev.clientY - shiftY + "px";
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", (ev) => {
  if (dragging) {
    draggedObject.style.position = "static";
    let placeholder = document.querySelector("#placeholder");
    container.removeChild(placeholder);
    dragging = false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}
#big-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.draggable {
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#placeholder {
  width: 90px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: dashed grey 5px;
}
```

```html
<body draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;">
    <div
      id="big-container"
      style="display: flex; background-color: rgb(76, 104, 95);"
    >
      <div
        style="background-color: rgb(204, 125, 111);"
        class="draggable"
      ></div>
      <div
        style="background-color: rgb(170, 214, 120);"
        class="draggable"
      ></div>
      <div
        style="background-color: rgb(129, 212, 167);"
        class="draggable"
      ></div>
      <div
        style="background-color: rgb(162, 137, 196);"
        class="draggable"
      ></div>
    </div>

  </body>
```